# R - Per group computations - data.table and aggregate()

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I want to do simple computations by groups. As often I used `aggregate`. To compute the `sum` of my `var` by groups `gp1`, `gp2`, and `gp3` I did:

```
m.temp  <- aggregate(var ~ gp1 + gp2 + gp3, df, sum)
```

It works well but it was very slow. Before doing it in datatable, I wanted to try to change the syntax of the function to speed the process. I then did:

```
m.temp2 <- aggregate(df$var, 
                     list(df$gp1, df$gp2, df$gp3), 
                     sum)
```

Unfortunately for me, a simple verification showed me that these computations are not equivalent.

```
> identical(m.temp, m.temp2)
[1] FALSE
```

Variable names are different, but worse, there is a difference of 19 477 observations (rows) between these 2 results and it is not because of some `NAs` presence...

Here comes then My first question: how come? What is the difference between these 2 syntaxes?

To understand which syntax is the good one, I tried to do it using simple data.table process. Unfortunately I Couldnt get any result since my syntax is not correct, but I do not understand what I missed. I tied:

```
m.temp4 <- df[, list(sum = sum(df$var)), 
                      by = list(gp1, gp2, gp3)]
```

finally, I also tried to directly aggregate a new column, with the same absence of results...

```
df[, new.col := sum(var), by = list(gp1, gp2, gp3)]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try `df[, .(sum = sum(var)), by = .(gp1, gp2, gp3)]`  we don't need the `df$var`, it will select the whole column instead of values in the group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the dataset is `data.table` or else convert to one with `setDT`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new_col := sum(var), by = .(gp1, gp2, gp3)]
```

---

In the OP's post, `sum` was done on the whole column `df$var` instead of the 'var' elements inside the group, resulting in a single `sum` value. Remove the `df$` and use the unquoted column name.

NOTE: The `:=` creates a new column.  If the intention is to summmarise, place it in `list` or `.()`

```
setDT(df)[, .(new_col =  sum(var)), by = .(gp1, gp2, gp3)]
```

---

Another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(gp1, gp2, gp3) %>%
    summarise(new_col = sum(var))
```

for creating a new column, replace `summarise` with `mutate`

Comment: m.temp  <- aggregate(var ~ gp1 + gp2 + gp3, df, sum)
m.temp3 <- setDT(df)[, .(new_col = sum(var)), by = .(gp1, gp2, gp3)]

are equivalent normally, the present of NAs apart... the problem is, if I do the mean of both, removing the NAs, 

mean(m.temp3$new_col, na.rm=TRUE)
mean(m.temp$var, na.rm=TRUE)

I have a 2 different numbers, the second one being 10 times (more or less) the first one...

Comment: @TeYaP  It is not equivalent normally.  the `:=` creates a column while `aggregate` summarises.  The issue is with `aggregate` as it removes NA rows when ever there is a single NA in any of the columns you need to add `na.action = na.pass` along with `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: @TeYaP  Okay, I was referring to `df[, new.col := sum(var), by = list(gp1, gp2, gp3)] ` in your code

Comment: @TeYaP  anyway, I suggested one reason for the `aggregate` results to be different.  You may disagree

Comment: the data.table way is then "more efficient"...
PS: edit your answer, you forgot a "T", 2nd line, "setDT"

Comment: #akrun Do you know a way to add na.rm in the data.table code? I tried df[, new.col := sum(var, na.rm=TRUE), by = list(gp1, gp2, gp3)] but it does not work

Comment: @TeYaP   For me, it is working fine `as.data.table(mtcars)[, sum(mpg, na.rm = TRUE), list(vs, am)]`